# What's the Android Devices section of Google Dashboard for?

Tags: google-account

I noticed the Android Devices section of Dashboard is empty for me. I've had 3 android devices so far, all synced with my Google account. The Android Market section of Dashboard correctly shows my download count.

What is that section for? Why don't my devices show up under it?

Answer (score 2):

On my dashboard it shows my devices and a list of application data that is stored on the server. 
Do you have backup enabled to Google servers? It is usually a setting in the Privacy menu.

Comment: My account stuff like Contacts are, but I'm not sure it's called a backup. Are your devices ICS? My latest phone is Gingerbread.

Comment: Both mine are Gingerbread. The contacts and Calendars are part of a regular sync with your Google account. The backup is a separate setting that backs up thingslike Wi-Fi passwords, Keyboard and dictionary settings, etc.

Comment: Huh, I have that set to back up too. IS there some way to check that it's working? Still nothing in google dashboard